# Inserting a delay between screen updates using Val and GTK3

Tags: vala, gtk3

I am learning Vala and GTK3 in a Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) environment.  To do so, I have written a Game of Life simulation.  So far so good.  What I would like to do is insert a delay (say 2 seconds) between each screen update.  I have investigated the Glib.TimeoutSource function and it seems over-elaborate for my needs. Are there other options?  If TimeoutSource is indeed the way to go, are there any examples you might recommend.
Thank you.

Mike

Update:  It turns out to be ridiculously easy ...

```
public void onRunButtonClicked(Button source)
{
  Timeout.add_seconds(3, updateDraw);
}

private bool updateDraw()
{
  game.determineBirthsAndDeaths();
  game.applyBirthsAndDeaths();
  queue_draw();
  iterationsLabel.set_text("Iteration: %5d".printf(game.getIterationCount()));      
  return true;
}
```

The first method sets the timer.  The second one executes every three seconds (in this example).  Now I have to add a stop button and get my updateDraw method to return false when the stop button is pressed.  More to learn ...

Comment: I think you should write and accept an answer yourself so people know you issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onRunButtonClicked(Button source)
{
  Timeout.add_seconds(3, updateDraw);
}

private bool updateDraw()
{
  game.determineBirthsAndDeaths();
  game.applyBirthsAndDeaths();
  queue_draw();
  iterationsLabel.set_text("Iteration: %5d".printf(game.getIterationCount()));      
  return true;
}
```